# angularJS - ui-grid with multiple non-modal popups with the same controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, popup, angular-ui-grid

I am using angularJS and [ui-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid) to create a grid. Now I would like to edit some complex cells in a [non-modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_box#Modeless) popup.

Here you can find a working plunker for what I have done so far:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HXuka8RGhhVrBVpTuiHe?p=preview

As you can see I am using the same controller for all popups and all popups share all their data in one scope (check the console prompt for the shared data object). This is working fine so far.

Now the issue: If there is one open popup and you open a second one both will show the same data. The first popup changes its data because of angulars data binding.
That's why I'm using a `ng-init` in `app.js` at line 56 to bind the rowID and colID to the popup. If I inspect the DOM it seems to be ok and unchanged after the second popup opens, but obviously there is something wrong.

So how can I achieve that all popups don't change their values if another one gets opened? Breaking the data binding is not an option.

Thanks for your help